# How to Generate Combinations by Spreading Array Values based on Shared Scenario in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, arraylist

I have a multidimensional array with the following structure:

```php
array(
    array(["AF2021A"], ["AF2021B"], ["AF2020C"]), 
    array(["IR2022A","IR2021A"], ["IR2022B","IR2021B"], ["IR2022C","IR2021C"], ["IR2022D","IR2021D","IR2020D"]
));
```

I would like to spread its data based on a shared scenario. For each array in the first dimension, I want to generate new sets of arrays, considering both the year (e.g., 2021, 2020) and the order number of the alphabet (e.g., A, B, C, D).

The expected results are as follows:

**[First Dimension Results]**

- AF2020C - AF2021A
- AF2020C - AF2021B
- AF2021A - AF2021B
- AF2021A - AF2020C
- AF2021B - AF2020C
- AF2021B - AF2021A

**[Second Dimension Results]**

- IR2020D - IR2021A
- IR2020D - IR2021B
- IR2020D - IR2021C
- IR2020D - IR2021D
- IR2020D - IR2022A
- IR2020D - IR2022B
- IR2020D - IR2022C
- IR2020D - IR2022D
- IR2021A - IR2021B
- IR2021A - IR2021C
- IR2021A - IR2021D
- IR2021A - IR2022A
- IR2021A - IR2022B
- IR2021A - IR2022C
- IR2021A - IR2022D
- IR2021B - IR2021C
- IR2021B - IR2021D
- IR2021B - IR2022A
- IR2021B - IR2022B
- IR2021B - IR2022C
- IR2021B - IR2022D
- IR2021C - IR2021D
- IR2021C - IR2022A
- IR2021C - IR2022B
- IR2021C - IR2022C
- IR2021C - IR2022D
- IR2021D - IR2022A
- IR2021D - IR2022B
- IR2021D - IR2022C
- IR2021D - IR2022D
- IR2022A - IR2022B
- IR2022A - IR2022C
- IR2022A - IR2022D
- IR2022B - IR2022C
- IR2022B - IR2022D
- IR2022C - IR2022D

I have attempted a few approaches, but they did not return the desired results. Unfortunately, I'm unable to share my source code as it is not suitable for sharing.

I'm seeking guidance on how to achieve all the combinations efficiently. Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to slightly ignore your outer array, I think you can work to address that. The code below appears to have the same results as you show. I'm writing strings into another array, I'm not really sure what your true expected output is supposed to be either. Also, I'm outputting an empty item, solely to match your spacing, you can either remove it or apply logic as needed.

First, we need to clean, de-duplicate (just in case) and sort the array:

```php
function cleanArray(array $array): array
{
    $clean = [];
    foreach ($array as $item) {
        array_push($clean, ...$item);
    }

    $clean = array_unique($clean);
    sort($clean);
    return $clean;
}
```

Then the main function walks the array, taking the first item out, loops over the remaining and appends, and repeats until there's only one thing left. The `switch/case` is up to you for any business logic for edge cases with missing or only one item.

```php
function processArray(array $array): array
{
    $array = cleanArray($array);
    switch (count($array)) {
        case 0:
            // Edge case, not sure
            return [];
        case 1:
            // Edge case again, not sure
            return [];
        case 2:
            return [sprintf('%1%s - %2$s', $array[0], $array[1])];
        default:
            $ret = [];
            while (count($array) >= 2) {
                $currentItem = array_shift($array);
                foreach ($array as $item) {
                    $ret[] = sprintf('%1$s - %2$s', $currentItem, $item);
                }
                $ret[] = '';
            }

            return $ret;
    }
}
```

This could also be done with recursion, but sometimes, if you can avoid that, it is much easier.

This can be tested with:

```php
print_r(processArray([["IR2022A", "IR2021A"], ["IR2022B", "IR2021B"], ["IR2022C", "IR2021C"], ["IR2022D", "IR2021D", "IR2020D"]]));
print_r(processArray([["AF2021A"], ["AF2021B"], ["AF2020C"]]));
```

The only thing that doesn't seem to match up is the third row in your first sample. I don't understand by `B` comes before `A`, is that a typo?

Comment: Thanks buddy it helps a lot, now I have to implement it for multi dismissions.